# Convert Batch to VBS

Tags: .net, vb.net, batch-file, vbscript

Hey I been trying to make a batch script to implement into my VB.NET application. What my application does is check if a new version is available, if it is it will download it into the app data file. Then it creates a Batch script, runs it and closes itself.

From here the batch script takes the updated version, takes it and replaces the outdated version. The batch script will run the updated version (it will be in the same directory as the outdated version since it has been moved) and run it. The batch file will then self destruct. I tried doing this but all it did was run the new version and that is it. It did not even self destruct? Here is my batch script:

```
@echo off
Type "file"
ping -n 10 localhost >nul 2>&1
xcopy /y "C:\Documents and Settings\Mumit\Application Data\Icarus" "C:\Documents and           Settings\Mumit\Desktop\Icarus\Icarus\Icarus\bin\Debug\Icarus"
start /d "C:\Documents and Settings\Mumit\Desktop\Icarus\Icarus\Icarus\bin\Debug" Icarus
DEL"file"
DEL %0
EXIT
```

As you can see it is only a couple of lines. Can anyone help me port it into a VBS? I would appreciate it.

This is how I wrote it in .NET:

```
 Dim s As New Text.StringBuilder
            s.Append("@echo off" + Environment.NewLine + "Type " + ChrW(34) + "file" + ChrW(34) +
                  Environment.NewLine + "ping -n 10 localhost >nul 2>&1" +
                  Environment.NewLine + "xcopy /y " + File2 + " " + File1 +
                  Environment.NewLine + "start /d " + ChrW(34) + Splitter(IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(CStr(Splitter(File1)))) + ChrW(34) + " " + IO.Path.GetFileName(CStr(Splitter(File1))) +
                  Environment.NewLine + "DEL" + ChrW(34) + "file" + ChrW(34) +
                  Environment.NewLine + "DEL %0" +
                  Environment.NewLine + "EXIT")
```

Comment: You can't delete a file that is in-use. So, a batch file cannot delete itself.

Comment: What OS are you using?  if later it would be best served to create a powershell script to do this behavior for you; and not worry about scripting environments.

Comment: I know I cannot delete a file that is in use. I ran the batch script and as you can see it waits 10 seconds before executing any more code. Once my .NET app runs the script it exits itself.

@Joe I have no knowledge what so ever in Powerscript and I want to to work for all Windows OS if that is possible.

Comment: I'm really confused as to why you are writing a batch script into a .net app that can do all of this without having to rely upon legacy artchitecture/plumbing.

Comment: Powershell 1.0 is available for all windows OS (at least from xp++).  In any event, if you write it as a .net compiled resource xp and others will be prompted for dependancies related to .net.  I'd suggest using the System.IO

Comment: How can a file be moved if it is in use? That is not possible. Unless I do this via Codedom and execute a new application to do all this, but I would rather have a self destructing native script. As for powershell does it have any dependencies? I would rather use a VBS or Batch script since I am more familiar with them, even though I do not know how to write in said language.

Answer (score 1):

If your using .NET already - and having it execute create a batch... you may as well, just do batch. If you are using it as a gateway to be able to do traditional file copies... then your doing it wrong.

Use the following instead of your batch commands:

```
System.IO.File.Copy(SourceFile, DestinationFolder, true);
```

This will overwrite the existing file(s) and be done with it.

Note Powershell Script for copying:

```
Copy-Item c:\scripts\test.txt c:\test
```

Comment: I am overwriting the .NET app itself with the updated version. The batch must do this while the .NET app closes itself. You cannot overwrite a application that is running.

Comment: you can on dispose or close...or run as separate applicaton and hooked to your application.  Or as a powershell execution script tied to your onclose method.  Or on specific dates/times/modified dates etc.

Comment: I did not know this, I will test it out and post back with results.

Comment: Your best bet is to tie a powershell copy-item script to the closing of the app.  It will fire in a separate thread to my knowledge and if just called will run in console; and should allow the app to close.  Though, you may need to add a wait state.

Comment: Can you write me a quick Powershell script? I have no knowledge on them so it will be tedious.

Comment: [System.IO.File]::Copy("c:\dir1\filename.ext","c:\dir2\filename.ext");  Place in notepad - save as copyfile.ps1  :) All Scripted.

Answer (score 1):

This is fundamentally a windows OS question.
I have come across this issue before doing deployment in some very custom scenarios where other deployment methods are not a suitable choice.

You cannot delete a file that is in-use: **TRUE**

You cannot rename a file that is in-use: **FALSE**

***YOU CAN RENAME ANY EXE or DLL FILE BEING USED by a .NET EXE*** that is running and using the file (and possibly in many other scenerios)

What you can do is this.

1) Rename all files in the program folder with some common but detectable prefix or suffix. Such as "ShadowCopy_TIMESTAMP_ORIGINALFILE.EXT" where you use a timestamp to ensure a unique file name.

2) Copy all your new files into the directory, none will confilict because they were renamed.

3) Restart your application with the new EXE just created.

4) In the start up of the application run a routine in a background thread that waits a few seconds and deletes all files with the pattern "**ShadowCopy_***" to perform clean up of the unneeded files.

*(You can do this directly in the .NET application or in another language that is easier to deal with files such as a VBS script)*

I used this method for a server scenario where multiple copies of the same EXE are spawned all the time, at different times, and some run as long as 24 hours. I cannot kill the spawned copy as it would prevent it from doing its work but I want new code to apply to all new running instances. In this case the "Delete" of the old files needs to be fault tollerant because many of the renamed files are still in use.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at the ClickOnce technology. It's been specifically created to handle this exact requirement:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s5tdc033(v=vs.80).aspx

It relies on the fact that the application was created using a ClickOnce installer, but if it was you can just do this to get the latest version of the application:

```
Sub UpdateApplication()
    If My.Application.IsNetworkDeployed Then
        My.Application.Deployment.Update()
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Pablo, it's the quick and the dead around here :)

Comment: I checked this and it's not really what I want. The updates will be hosted on my own server and my security panel need's to decrypt the bytes and parse them through an anti-decipher function before it is reconstructed and downloaded fully. I really want to do it using the Batch/VBS scripts, not a work a round. Thanks for that though I may use it in the future.

Comment: So the download is encrypted, I see. Now, nothing would prevent any user from just copying the unencrypted files afterwards to another computer, correct?
These suggestions, such as ClickOnce, PS, etc., are not actually workarounds, but suggestions to ways to solve it without reinventing the wheel. A lot of this has been already solved for you. Just something to keep in mind ;)

Comment: Yeah I understand but I really want to use VBS or Batch. This makes more sense to me at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into ClickOnce deployment? 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t71a733d%28VS.80%29.aspx

It handles these automatic updates that you are trying to cover here. Just beware of the security limitations, but it could save you a lot of time.

Now, in situations where I wanted to handle this manually, I would usually have a separate executable that handled updates.
That way, you could close the application to update and start the updater.
And to avoid the same problem (not being up to date) with the updater itself, the actual application would update the updater prior to executing. That way you'd guarantee that anything could be updated and all would end up up to date.

Comment: I checked this and it's not really what I want. The updates will be hosted on my own server and my security panel need's to decrypt the bytes and parse them through an anti-decipher function before it is reconstructed and downloaded fully. I really want to do it using the Batch/VBS scripts, not a work a round. Thanks for that though I may use it in the future.

Answer (score 0):

```
using System.IO;

// C# (Copy Files)
File.Copy(File_From, File_To);
```

OR

```
// C# (Move Files)
File.Move(File_From, File_To);
```

Here is a repeatable function for either:

```
Using System.IO;

Public Class FileOperation
{
    public void MoveFile(from_file, to_file)
    {
        try
        {
            System.IO.File.Move(from_file, to_file);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            string message = "Error In Move";
            debug(ex, message);
        }
    }

    public void CopyFile(from_file, to_file)
    {
        try 
        {
            System.IO.File.Copy(from_file, to_file);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
             string message = "Error In Copy";
             debug(ex, message);
        }
    }

    public void DeleteFile(delete_file)
    {
        try
        {
             System.IO.File.Delete(delete_file);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            string message = "Error In Delete";
            debug(ex, message);
        }
    } 

    public void debug(Exception ex, string message)
    {
         Console.Write(message+/n+ex.data);
    }
}
```

In Your App call:

```
FileOperation.MoveFile("c:\movethisfile.txt","d:\movethisfile.txt");
```

Or At least something similar to this.

Comment: If you read my post you would understand that I want to do this via Batch/VBS. If I try to overwrite the running process with another file, it will throw an error. It is not possible. I need VBS/Batch, not another application.

Comment: I suppose I'm lost ...I never have had a need of using batch/vbs to delete/migrate/move files even if in automation.  I use powershell religiously for file-based operations like that;  At least not since the 90's

Comment: I have been suggested Powershell 1.0 and use that as a substitute to Batch/VBS but I have never heard of this language/scripting language so I cannot do anything about it.